# SQL Group by along with same account number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I do have table structure like below

[image]

My requirement is I have to group by account number and description and show the total amounts like below

[image]

I have tried wiriting the group

```
SELECT AC_NUMBER, AC_NAME, SUM(ISNULL(DEBIT,0)) DEBIT, SUM(ISNULL(CREDIT,0)) CREDIT
FROM AC_TRANSACTION
GROUP BY AC_NUMBER, AC_NAME
```

but account number 1234-00 is summed up all amount and showing in one line like below
[image]

Basically Trasnaction_id is tied up with first table.
transaction id for the first table in order is , 3344,3345,3355,3356,3467,3468 ,4123,4124, like this

Every time 2 transaction will be created one is BOA and with other description 
so if you order by transaction_id you will get the first table order above
How do we achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain more about the expected output, and why it appears that way?

Comment: You are assuming that your table is ordered, but there doesn't appear to be a column here where the order can be determined in order to perform this sort-of group-by. Is there a date or timestamp field present on this table that establishes the order you share in your first sample data screenshot? In other words, there is no reason why these `BOA` lines should appear "above" every other non-BOA line and your expected output is highly based on that ordering.

Comment: @Domnic why is Boa split into 3 records?

Comment: It appears that there are more columns to your tables than what you are showing, and the expected output depends somehow on those other tables.  For example, there may be a month or fiscal period column that is being used as an additional grouping to make the separate entries for BOA.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the grouping you expect.

Comment: I think some information is missing.

Comment: I have  edited the questions with more info

Comment: @Domnic my question is how you identify the group? For example, how do you know the row 1 could match row2? Why not row1 matches row 4? If you want to say the credit amount equals the debit amount, I will have a new question: in your original data, do the credit amount always equal the debit amount for each group?

Answer (score 0):

If you have identity_field in your table:
Example:

```
DECLARE @A table ( identity_field int identity(1,1),prod_id NVARCHAR(10) , v int)
INSERT into @A(prod_id,v)
VALUES('A',10),('A',20),('B',30),('A',40),('B',50),('B',60),('B',70),('A',80),('C',90);

WITH A AS (
select row_number()over (order by prod_id,identity_field) nr,*
from @A)
,B AS(
SELECT identity_field-nr group_field,*
FROM A
)
select MIN(identity_field) tran_id,prod_id, SUM(v) sum_v
FROM B
GROUP BY prod_id,group_field
order by MIN(identity_field)
```

for your table:

```
WITH A AS (
select identity_field-row_number()over (order by ACCOUNT_NUMBER,DESCRIPTION,identity_field) group_field,*
from YOUT_TABLE)

select MIN(identity_field) tran_id,ACCOUNT_NUMBER,DESCRIPTION, SUM(DEBIT) transact_debit,SUM(CREDIT) transact_credit
FROM A
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER,DESCRIPTION,group_field
order by MIN(identity_field)
```